# How to filter values on foreign key field editing?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a three simple models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

class Session(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, through='TaskInSession')
```

and

```
class TaskInSession(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

For session editing I have:

```
class SessionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TaskInSessionInline,]
    exclude = ('tasks', )
```

Is it possible to add tasks filterting by tag possibility, for easy task selection on session editing?

Answer (score 0):

you should have in models.py your Tag class defined. Maybe something like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Then in your views.py you get the desired Tag. For instance:

```
desired_tag = Tag.objects.get(Name='some_name') # you could as well get the desired tagby the pk attribute.
```

Finally, Get all the tasks associated with that Tag. Example:

```
filtered_tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(tags=desired_tag)
```

The query you are looking would be filtered_tasks.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I allow user filtering tasks by tag while session editing? To reduce number of items by themselves.